# Command line argument to open Action Center Settings

Tags: windows, command-line, action-center

What or is there a command to open the action center settings?

I want a command that opens [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emJwG.png) screen specifically. I know that I can open the generic action center by running "wscui.cpl", but that is not specifically what I want to do.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct command to do that but you can use a script like this one.

Create a new text file, paste this code in it:

```
Option Explicit
Dim WshShell:Set WshShell=CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
WshShell.run "rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL wscui.cpl", 1
Wscript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys("+{TAB}")
WshShell.SendKeys("+{TAB}")
WshShell.SendKeys("+{TAB}")
WshShell.SendKeys("+{TAB}")
WshShell.SendKeys("+{TAB}")
WshShell.SendKeys("+{TAB}")
WshShell.SendKeys("+{TAB}")
WshShell.SendKeys("+{TAB}")
Wscript.Sleep 10
WshShell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
```

Save it under this name `wscuisettings.vbs`. double click on the file.

Answer (score 3):

just make the shortcut of the adress and execute the shortcut via command line.

open it first using the wscui.cpl, then click the button you want to display the window. in the adress bar right-click on the text "change action center settings" then click "copy address". then paste shortcut in desktop.

once you make the shortcut you can use it using cmd line.

Comment: Neat solution ;)

Answer (score -1):

With AHK it is shorter

```
; Open Action Center
ControlGet, ShellTray, Hwnd,, TrayButton1, ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd
ControlClick,, ahk_id %ShellTray%
```

The direct programmatic way is:

```
SendMessage, 0x111, ???,,, ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd
```

but I do not know the command number to send.

Comment: Oh no! This is for opening the Open Action Center, not the settings.